How can I set the comment color in code blocks rendered by reveal.js?
For my presentation, I use reveal.js 5.0.2 in cloudogu's container, external markdown and the beige theme. In C++ code blocks, comments are hard to read (grey on black background). I would like to change that color. Which attribute of the CSS should I modify?
